# What is the best way to send logs from ELK to Splunk?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, splunk

I would like to integrate ELK with Splunk but seems that I cannot find a very good tutorial on how to do so. I came across ELK http output but I cannot seem to make it work.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to send data from Logstash to Splunk?  If you are you can always use the tcp, udp or syslog logstash outputter.  Setup Splunk to listen to on one of those ports and you should be good to go